# GitHub Pages Page Not Found for React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages

I am trying to publish my single page website to github pages, but I've run into an issue. When I go to the link for my website, it gives me a 404 error with this message: "File not found. The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file. If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL. For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file."

I've looked at the documentation, watched videos, and looked up other people who are having this issue, but nothing will solve it.

I have a main and a gh-pages branch. Right now I have it set to build from the gh-pages branch. If I change it to main I get the same issue.

Here is my package.json file:

```
  "homepage": "http://bpyle02.github.io/portfolio",
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "aos": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "autoprefixer": "9",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3",
    "postcss": "7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icon": "^1.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router": "^6.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scroll-into-view": "^1.10.1",
    "scroll-into-view": "^1.16.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d build",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the link to the repo: https://github.com/bpyle02/portfolio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upload *only the contents* of your `build` folder to the `gh-pages` branch. I think it will benefit you to read about [how GitHub Pages works](https://pages.github.com/).

---

The `create-react-app` documentation explains how to address your scenario:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Here's the most important information (without setting this before building your app, it won't work):

> Open your `package.json` and add a `homepage` field for your project:
>
> ```json
> "homepage": "https://myusername.github.io/my-app",
> ```
>
> Create React App uses the `homepage` field to determine the root URL in the built HTML file.

This might also be relevant to your app:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths

Comment: I already added that line to my code

Comment: You need to upload _only the contents_ of your `build` folder to the `gh-pages` branch. I have also added this to my answer. All sorted now?

Comment: I have removed everything except the build folder in gh-pages and I a still getting the same error.

Comment: Not the build folder itself, just it’s _contents_: everything inside it.

Comment: Ok, I put the folder contents into the gh-pages branch and it works now! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working!

Comment: `"homepage": "./"` will work for any url, no need to hardcode specific address

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231331/github-pages-page-not-found-for-react-app/70231417?noredirect=1#comment132823227_70231417) "_...will work for any url_": @Konrad The CRA documentation ([linked in the answer](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths)) explains that there are cases where that's not true. Some of the specifics were initially discussed in [facebook/create-react-app#1487](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1487)

Comment: The #1487 has been fixed 5 years ago. And client-side routing doesn't work with github pages (except hash routing which is unaffected)