# Why is my reactjs application showing a blank page when deployed with github pages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

My React-js app works fine when I use npm start to run it on localhost:3000.

However, when I deploy it, I can only see a blank page.
There is also an error that is displayed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at index.js:974:1
    at index.js:973:1
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.js:972:1)
    at n (index.js:14:1)
    at e.exports (index.js:50:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:4:1)
    at f ((index):1:1250)
    at 239 (Profile.jsx:188:28)
    at f ((index):1:1250)
    at 148 (login-page-pic.png:1:41)
```

[Blank screen when deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emUMQ.png)

I have run npm build and I have made sure that the branch settings are at "master", which is where the build files are.

There are no errors when I run npm build and when I run npm deploy.

My github repository for the whole application is here.

https://github.com/dawg420/friendzone-deploy

Comment: You probably forgot to set the `homepage` configuration to point to your gh-pages URL. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Pages Page Not Found for React App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231331/github-pages-page-not-found-for-react-app)

Comment: I have set the homepage to https://dawg420.github.io/friendzone-deploy

I have confirmed that my master branch (which is where I have built) only contains those files.

Comment: @yuchen But GitHub no longer uses master, not since late 2020: https://github.com/github/renaming. I mention in my answer this is probably the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow "[ReactApp Deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages)", it includes the command in the package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b main -d build",
                        ^^^^^^^
```

I would specify the [branch option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#user-content-optionsbranch) in order to *not* use the default branch `master`, but `main`.
(That is your issue: your site is currently [generated in the `master` branch](https://github.com/dawg420/friendzone-deploy/tree/master))

And I would double-check the [publication source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) of your repository, to make sure it is "branch `main`, folder `build`".

Comment: I've deployed it to main, and now only the readme file is shown

Comment: @yuchen The key is https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site: configure a branch and a folder, make sure to deploy to that branch and folder, and it will work.